# Electric field line for $\mathbf{\vec{E}}$ = E$_0$ x$^2$ $\mathbf{\hat{x}}$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields

Though this will seem like a homework problem, I hope you will believe me when I say its not.

I wanted to know the field line depiction of $\mathbf{\vec{E}}$ = E$_0$ x$^2$ $\mathbf{\hat{x}}$.

The lines must be very far away at $x=0$ and crowded as $x\to+\infty$ or $x\to-\infty$. I don't know how to draw this.

Comment: Hint: the electric field points in the x-direction everywhere.

Comment: BTW, the Homework Tag does not necessarily mean it is homework. It is actually sort of a homework question, but one that---from my point of view---is sort of reasonable. Another hint: try to get the charge distribution by applying the gradient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The divergence of the electric field
$$\nabla \cdot \vec{E} = 2 xE_0 = \rho/\epsilon,$$
where $\rho$ is the charge density.

This the charge density is constant along lines of fixed $x$, is zero anywhere along the y-axis, negative for $x<0$ and positive for $x>0$.

In the field line model, the direction of the lines indicates the direction of the E-field - so in this case, horizontal lines, parallel to the x-axis. The spacing between the field lines represents the field strength, so this must grow (symmetrically) with perpendicular distance from the y-axis.

Practically this would be accomplished by *creating* new field lines representing where electric field lines begin (on positive charges) and end (on negative charges). Obviously this is just a sketch, since you can't draw enough field lines to match the number of discrete charges in any realistic charge distribution.

My attempt is below. I apologise for the draughtmanship, I wasn't prepared to spend any more time on it. The key things to understand are that (a) that in reality there is no variation of E-field in the y-direction; (b) the field lines are created and destroyed according to the charge density, so there must be more field lines per unit y-axis length as $|x|$ increases and no field lines at $x=0$; (c) all the field lines must be horizontal; (d) you would repeat this pattern for different values of $y$; (e) If you wanted to continue fiurther away from the y-axis, you would need to add even more lines.

[image: E-field]

Answer (score 0):

The electric field vectors in your example are parallel to the x-axis and these vectors are *tangent* to the field lines and so, the field lines are parallel to the x-axis unlike what you've drawn in the [initial version](https://physics.stackexchange.com/revisions/339134/1) of your question.

Typically, we say something like 'the number of lines through a unit area normal to the field is proportional to the strength of the electric field'.

Since the strength of the field increases as the distance from the plane $x=0$ increases but the field lines are always parallel to the x axis, it isn't clear to me how to make a field line diagram.

Perhaps, rather then the density of the field lines, the 'transparency' (from 100% (white background) at $x=0$ to 0% (pure black) for $x \rightarrow \infty$ of the lines could vary with $x$?

Answer (score 0):

Lines of electric a visual aid which perhaps in this case not necessarily the best way to visualise the electric field.

You can think of "counting" the lines passing at right angles through an area which will the electric flux.
So the "number" of field lines divided by the area gives a measure of the electric field strength.
Usually this is shown diagrammatically by the separation of electric field lines; if the electric field lines are close together the electric field is stronger than if the electric field lines are further apart.

An important property of electric field lines is they start on a positive charges and end on negative charges.
In your example the electric field at $x=0$ is zero and whatever diagram is draw will show electric field lines parallel to the x-axis going in the positive x-direction ending up on negative charges when $x<0$ and starting on positive charges when $x>0$.

The electric field only depends on $x$ and so is the same for all $y$ and $z$ values.
Imagine a tube of base area $A$ (which can be made arbitrarily small) with long side parallel to the x-axis as shown in the left hand diagram.
The central axis of the cylinder being along a line where $y$ and $z$ are constant.

[image]

What can you say about the "number" of electric field lines at various positions inside the tube?
Their "number" is proportional to $x^2$.

So by drawing a graph of "number" against position $x$ you can get a visualisation of the number of electric field lines which are passing through the tube at each position $x$.

In the right hand diagram there is one line that starts at $x=1$.
By the time $x=2$ is reached there are four lines and at $x=3$ there are nine lines.
One could show this increased density of lines by making a line thicker (thickness proportional to $x^2$) as shown at the bottom or by having the line starting out as white and then going through various shades of grey tending towards black.

Perhaps the best way of visualising this field is to draw equipotential surfaces which will be planes of constant values of $x$ making the $x=0$ plane the zero of potential?